# Twitter Bootstrap table resize , row overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, resize, html-table

I'm stuck with tables in twitter bootstrap. No matter what I try I'm not able to get my table within the span, I think it has something to do with the bootstrap CSS, I need my table rows to be justified within the span or hero-unit.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table  id="table" 
          class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped form-group">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <th>Sl. No.</th>
         <th class="">Name</th>
         <th>C/NC</th>
         <th class="">Quantity</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addmorebutton" 
                    value="Add" onclick="addRow();"/></th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="templateRow">
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="In Words"></td>
        <td class=""><input type="text" placeholder="In Words"></td>
        <td>
           <select class="input-sm col-lg-2">
              <option>Consumable</option>
              <option>Non Consumable</option>
           </select>
        </td>
        <td class=""><input type="text" placeholder="In Numbers"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="In Numbers"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="addmorebutton" 
                   value="Delete" onclick="delRow(this);"/></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a test site? I can't tell anything from the code you have provided

Comment: Do you have to use tables? Bootstrap comes with a grid system http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying position a `table` by styling a parent `span` element, you need to make the span into a block level element. Span is inherently not a block-level element; therefore, it collapses and will not contain the table within page flow. Using `block` or `inline-block` is one of the ways you can change a span to contain properly. To make it easier however, you could always just use a block level element to begin with such as a `div` or style the table itself.

Try `display:block;` on your `<span>` CSS. This will force it to contain its child elements.

Without more information, it is hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish.
More information on block-level elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements